# Most efficient algorithm to convert array A into array B of unknown lengths

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of indefinite length from which the user chooses to add/remove components. To reflect the changes in the backend I must perform ajax requests.
My question is what would be the most efficient way to reflect those changes?

Currently I have two approaches in mind:

1.) Find the differences between the two arrays and then appropriately address the differences by adding the missing / removing the extra elements one by one.

2.) Make use of the remove all service to remove every single item in the array in the backend using a single request then adding one by one whatever is in the second array.

At the first glance approach 1 seems to be better with small changes in particular. However if the user decides to remove 80 or so elements from the array and only add 2 more then approach 2 outclasses approach 1.

Perhaps there is a better solution? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could send a compressed JSON of the array to the backend. If it's just text data, you'd have minimal overhead, and no need to keep track of the diff. You also don't need to keep track of what to delete and what to add, since the backend's contents are refreshed with every request.

Comment: You can also just send the actual add/remove updates through as they happen instead of calculating the difference.

Comment: @Dukeling ya that makes writing code easy but in my model once I submit save changes is only when I want the backend code to be updated. The user could potentially do a few changes then change his mind and press cancel

Comment: There isn't a general rule to follow here. The best approach would depend on (a) how big the arrays are (b) how many changes happen over what interval (c) how often you want the changes to appear on the backend (d) whether you have any space constraints (e) how fast things happen in this environment (network speed, disk read/write speed, etc). Although if you need to send the entire array B through to find the difference (as opposed to buffering B), that approach sounds like a terrible idea (because then you might as well just send through the entire A to the backend).

Comment: @Dukeling a.) Arrays could be however long. Though I presume they wont be very long: max 50ish b.) The user requests for the array for a particular object and then can make changes to this array if he wants to and only when he presses edit are all the changes to the array computed/ updated in the backend. c.) Same as b.) only when the user presses edit. d.) No space concerns. e.) I can't tell how fast the environment is since I am interning and have no access to the servers (but each request does take a couple of seconds) -- main reason why I want to limit ajax requests. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Assuming each element of the array is at most only a few kilobytes, if each array only has like 50 elements and these are from a small number of users doing things (i.e. the requests happen at most every few seconds), it probably couldn't matter less which approach you pick. Even the slowest approach should be more than adequate. Go for the one that involves the least back-and-forth. If the arrays were megabytes, gigabytes or bigger and/or many requests came through per second, then it would matter.